# Magento adding a section to product-collateral via local xml not working correctly

Tags: magento, magento-layout-xml

I have followed this article to add the product reviews into the collateral section on a product page:
http://www.crearegroup-ecommerce.co.uk/blog/magento-tutorials/product-reviews-on-product-view-page.php

I have added the following code to my local.xml:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
       <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_review" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
          <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/>
       </block>
    </reference>
```

And the following code in view.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_review') ?>
```

The above was added just between some other calls to getChildHtml (in the collateral section)

**Issue:** The reviews and form are getting added to the end of the page and not in the collateral section?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: tabs available in the "modern" theme, so check tabs.phtml file from modern theme!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the reference name from `content` to `product.info`. When you are adding it into the content node (which is a `core/text_list` block), it will automatically append it to the bottom. That is why you need to put it inside the `product.info` node, and then reference it in your template.